# Unity3d Admob rewarded video ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm having troubles showing the rewarded video ad from admob plugin in Unity3d.
First of all this is my script:

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour {
    private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_AD_UNIT_HERE";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_AD_UNIT_HERE";
#else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);

        //Show Ad
        showAdd(rewardBasedVideo);
    }

    private void showAdd(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo)
    {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            //Subscribe to Ad event
            rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        }
    }

    private void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward e)
    {
        Debug.Log("30 monedas ;)");
        Debug.Log(e);
    }
}
```

I run the `RequestRewardVideo()` Method with a button, but nothing happens. I tried to run the `requestrewardvideo()` method in the `start()` and `showAdd()` form the button but only shows the video 1/3 times... whats wrong with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I run the `RequestRewardVideo()` Method with a button, but nothing happens.**

You must maintain some time difference between load and show Ad because Ad takes some time in loading. when you call in showAd just After loading  `rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded()` return false.

So call `requestrewardvideo()` from `start()` and on button Click call `showAdd()`.

```
private void showAdd(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo) {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            //Subscribe to Ad event
            rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        }else {
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
        }
}
```

Also Ad A listener When Ad Close and request to loadAd again there. So that each time `rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded()` return true.

**EDIT**

```
rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;  //Ad listener to your rewardBasedVideo

public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{ 
    //   Load it here
}
```

Comment: "Also Ad A listener When Ad Close and request to loadAd again there. So that each time rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded() return true." That's the clue, how can i add a listener? thank you ;)

Comment: You're amazing Thank's! I understand now the logic! ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this plugin  https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob 
then  code will like this.

load video

```
   Admob.Instance().loadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
```

Shown at game over , check that the video is ready before showing it:

```
   if (Admob.Instance().isRewardedVideoReady()) {
     Admob.Instance().showRewardedVideo();
   }
```

handle ad event

```
Admob.Instance().videoEventHandler += onInterstitialEvent;
    void onInterstitialEvent(string eventName, string msg)
    {
    Debug.Log("handler onAdmobEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    if (eventName == AdmobEvent.onAdLoaded)
    {
        Admob.Instance().showRewardedVideo();
    }
    if(eventName==AdmobEvent.onAdFail){
    Debug.log(msg);
    }

}
```