# AdMob Loading Issues

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I'm using AdMob for Unity for an Android game I'm building.

The issues I'm having is with a reward ad not showing when it's ready.

The code in question.

```
if(rewardBasedVideoAd.IsLoaded())
{
    ErrorLog.text = "Ad Is Loaded.";
    rewardBasedVideoAd.Show();
}
```

The IsLoaded is returning true, meaning the ad is ready to show, the error label is taking the new value "Ad Is Loaded." but the ad itself doesn't show all the time.

Sometimes it will show on the first click, other times it doesn't and will take a few clicks before it shows.

This seems a bit annoying for users so does anyone know why this is happening and what am I missing.

If this isn't an easy fix, I may try a loop that will try clicking it a few times until it has been shown.

EDIT

Thanks for the duplicate answer but the issue isn't with the IsLoaded() returning false, as it returns true and displays a message in the log next to the ad.Show() function.

CODE SNIPPETS

```
void Start () {
    RequestRewardBasedVideo();
}

private void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
    {
        AdReady = false;
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX";

        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleOnAdRewarded;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
        ErrorBox.text = "Ad Loaded!";

    }

public void ShowRewardVideo()
    {
        if(rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            ErrorBox.text = "Ad Shown!";
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorBox.text = "ADmob ad not loaded!";
        }
    }

public void ClickConfirmWatch()
    {
        ShowRewardVideo();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3d Admob rewarded video ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891119/unity3d-admob-rewarded-video-ads)

Comment: Hi abhishek, thanks for the reply but that isn't the issue I have.
The issue is when ad.IsLoaded() returns true, displays the log message in the if statement, and then doesn't show the advert.
It is intermittent as it was in that answer :)

Comment: when return true first time `ErrorLog.text` become `Ad Is Loaded.;`, sometimes `rewardBasedVideoAd.IsLoaded()` return true when ads is loaded otherwise return false so sometime you get ad.

Comment: Thanks again, it's the first time that's got an issue, the first time i try to show the ad, which is with a button press, the errortext is changed but no ad is shown. This makes it look as though rewardBasedVideoAd.IsLoaded() is called but doesn't show the ad.

Comment: will you please add some code snippets

Comment: Hi again,
Added more snippets at the bottom of the OP